# Confusions with the profile visibility in a social web application

Tags: website-design, user-profile

I'm designing a community website. I don't have any experience in this. My confusion is, how do I distinguish what is visible to others and user using the website? I know what should I show to the user. Do I have to design like two different modes for self-view for the user and profile as visible to others, something like that? Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the rights of the "viewer" and the "user"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would have to design two different interfaces for

1. Self-view: Shows all details of one's profile, with the most important or most relevant information first (basically, showing name or designation to self is less relevant than showing say, next goal or next task to be completed)
2. User-view (all others): Show the basic and **permitted** personal details, along with quick actions maybe (add friend, follow, report user). Then show the details specific to the application.

Please click on my profile, your own profile and check how stackexchange shows it differently. Another great example is *LinkedIn*.

Another add-on would be to provide a button: "view public profile" within self-view page.